# Error installing cyhunspell in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm getting the following error in Google Colab when trying `!pip install cyhunspell`.

I've tried the following things, to no avail:

1. Installing different versions (1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.3, 1.1.3.post1, 1.1.4, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 2.0.2)
2. Updating `pip`
3. Updating `wheel`
4. Uninstalling and reeinstalling `gcc`
5. Deleting runtime and restarting all.

I'm using Python 3.10.12 and pip 23.1.2

**Error I'm getting:**

```
Collecting cyhunspell
  Downloading CyHunspell-1.3.4.tar.gz (2.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.7/2.7 MB 36.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```